# How to load laravel sidebar paginated data?

Tags: pagination, laravel-5.1

I am loading messages in sidebar. When next page is loaded it should load only messages of next page not whole page. My code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029097/laravel-sidebar-jscroll-query). In code ul is my side bar.